# Как правильно сказать (иск)?

Tags: лексика

Иск предъявляется К кому-то или кому-то?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Частенько слышал слышал "к кому-то", иногда даже от юристов.
Но правильно, конечно: иск предъявляют *кому*. 
Тут, видимо, историческое изменение управления: в словаре Ушакова ещё есть "иск к соседу" и т.п. Позднее уже только - кому.

Хотя пардон. В МАСе (1999 г.) тоже - "к кому". Ну тогда придётся признать варианты равноправными.